# how to submit a form from one application to other

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In my mvc application in need to submit the form from one application to another application.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

It is better you create web/WCF service in another app , so you can call it from your current website

Answer (score 1):

Depends where you want to do the POST from - client side of your web app or the server side?

- if you want to initiate the POST from client side, there's nothing inherently differently from creating a form that posts to your own server. Just point the URL the form submits the POST request to be on the server for the second app.
- if you want to initiate the POST from the server side of your application, while you are still processing the response of a request to your app, you can use the [`HttpWebRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) class. Here's some [example code](http://www.netomatix.com/HttpPostData.aspx) to get you started; you can find more articles and samples by searching the web for [httpwebrequest asp.net](http://www.bing.com/search?q=httpwebrequest+asp.net)

Answer (score -2):

Don't think so; because when you are doing a `POST`, you are counting on the `HttpContext.POST` to transfer the information.

But this `HttpContext.POST` is per web application, so there is no way to do a post across different web app.

Comment: `HttpWebRequest` class can be used from ASP.NET app to make outgoing requests to other servers.